# Spring boot start up failing

Tags: spring-boot

I am newbie to Spring, I have written a spring application. when I try to start the application its giving me below logs but application being shutdown.

could you please help me anyone if i am doing something wrong here  ?

```
2017-06-01 16:39:27.187  INFO 6040 --- [           main] com.slb.sims.flows.Application           : Starting Application on SLB-25QDSY1 with PID 6040 (D:\SLB\SpringPOCs\prjSpringJDBCWS\target\classes started by LTangirala in D:\SLB\SpringPOCs\prjSpringJDBCWS)
2017-06-01 16:39:27.191  INFO 6040 --- [           main] com.slb.sims.flows.Application           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-01 16:39:27.313  INFO 6040 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c34f934: startup date [Thu Jun 01 16:39:27 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-01 16:39:28.448  INFO 6040 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2f16c6b3: startup date [Thu Jun 01 16:39:28 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-01 16:39:28.452  INFO 6040 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
2017-06-01 16:39:28.592  INFO 6040 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2017-06-01 16:39:29.080  INFO 6040 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-01 16:39:29.095  INFO 6040 --- [           main] com.slb.sims.flows.Application           : Started Application in 2.342 seconds (JVM running for 3.083)
2017-06-01 16:39:29.096  INFO 6040 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c34f934: startup date [Thu Jun 01 16:39:27 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-01 16:39:29.098  INFO 6040 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M
```

Comment: You have to provide the detail code. Only error / exception is not understandable to detect problem.

Comment: Spring boot application won't act as daemon only if you make it daemon. In other words, spring boot application just run the main method of your spring boot application class and exit when it done. Of course, if your spring boot application is a web application(such as `spring-boot-starter-web` is there), your application will act as an web server and listen on specific port, 8080 as default, to serve for any request. Otherwise, the application won't block. Of course, you have many methods to block your application, but it won't be blocked by default.

Comment: I have below dependency in pom xml.

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>

please download the code from this link : [project export](https://app.box.com/s/vf3h0c07showo94sl8ycs8onfsv8ikd6)

Comment: If it is closing even after you have the spring-boot-starter-web defined then it may be because the dependent tomcat or any jars are not included for some reason. Give a try by upgrading the version of boot to the latest or let us know the version that you are using?

Comment: I am using below spring boot version 
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't have an embedded server like Tomcat in classpath. add it and it will fix the issue
for MAVEN add this dependancy in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for Gradle (build.gradle) add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this dependency to your pom.xml. 
After that it should work.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```